# Mysql não inicia no servidor!

Tags: mysql, linux

Não estou conseguindo iniciar o MySQL no console do servidor.
Segue *log* de erro do MySQL abaixo:

> /*************** /var/log/mysql/error.log ***************/
>
> 170525 10:50:35 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover
>   instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in
>   a future release. Please use the full name instead. 170525 10:50:35
>   [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. 170525 10:50:35 InnoDB: The
>   InnoDB memory heap is disabled 170525 10:50:35 InnoDB: Mutexes and
>   rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 170525 10:50:35 InnoDB: Compressed
>   tables use zlib 1.2.3.4 170525 10:50:35 InnoDB: Initializing buffer
>   pool, size = 128.0M 170525 10:50:35 InnoDB: Completed initialization
>   of buffer pool 170525 10:50:35 InnoDB: highest supported file format
>   is Barracuda. InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn
>   97859737067 170525 10:50:35 InnoDB: Database was not shut down
>   normally! InnoDB: Starting crash recovery. InnoDB: Reading tablespace
>   information from the .ibd files... InnoDB: Restoring possible
>   half-written data pages from the doublewrite InnoDB: buffer... InnoDB:
>   Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 97860968674 InnoDB:
>   1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up InnoDB: in
>   total 1 row operations to undo InnoDB: Trx id counter is 1C0C5A00
>   170525 10:50:35 InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the
>   database... InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 13:50:35 UTC - mysqld got
>   signal 11 ; This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible
>   that this binary or one of the libraries it was linked against is
>   corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured. This error can also be
>   caused by malfunctioning hardware. We will try our best to scrape up
>   some info that will hopefully help diagnose the problem, but since we
>   have already crashed,  something is definitely wrong and this may
>   fail.
>
> key_buffer_size=16777216 read_buffer_size=131072
>   max_used_connections=0 max_threads=151 thread_count=0
>   connection_count=0 It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
>   key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =
>   346700 K bytes of memory Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some
>   variables in the equation.
>
> Thread pointer: 0x0 Attempting backtrace. You can use the following
>   information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no messages
>   after this, something went terribly wrong... stack_bottom = 0
>   thread_stack 0x30000
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29)[0x7f975b99b719]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x483)[0x7f975b860ae3]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfcb0)[0x7f975a5aacb0]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6bbd45)[0x7f975bafdd45]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6bb2a8)[0x7f975bafd2a8]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6bb925)[0x7f975bafd925]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6a868b)[0x7f975baea68b]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6a9b51)[0x7f975baebb51]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x64925b)[0x7f975ba8b25b]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6779d9)[0x7f975bab99d9]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x6037b0)[0x7f975ba457b0]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a)[0x7f975a5a2e9a]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f9759cd33fd] The manual
>   page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
>   information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
>
> /******************************/

/*************** my.cnf ***************/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

/***********************************************/

Comment: Você chegou a ler o manual que ele te indica ali no final? *The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.*

Comment: Será que você pode adicionar também o arquivo my.cnf?

Comment: Adicionado @ZumodeVidrio